# JMeter random security questions

Tags: security, variables, random, jmeter

I am trying to configure JMeter test plan and in one of the thread groups, I need to read the displayed security questions and answer them correctly. The user needs to answer 3 questions that will be displayed randomly from the list of 5 that the user selected when setting up his account.

How would I go about this? I can control the same 5 questions for all the users(when registering), but I cannot control the 3 that will be displayed randomly during my test.

Any pointers? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The Question1 Value is parsed and the actual question and not the variable as in the original code, this is the response

```
<div class="aaaaa">
    <label class="aaaaa">Question1 Value?</label>
</div>


<div class="aaaaa">
    <label class="aaaaa">Question2 Value?</label>
</div>

<div class="aaaaa">
    <div class="bbbb">
        <input id="answer1" name="answer1" class="aaaaa" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="aaaaa">
    <div class="bbbb">
        <input id="answer2" name="answer2" class="aaaaa" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if I am using IF Controller in the response, how would I form the condition. I need to be able to create 3 if conditions(need to check for possible 3 conditions - q1&q2, q1&q3, q2&q3). Since the questions are displayed as labels, I am not sure how would I put the condition.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the HTTP response and the next HTTP request to send the answers for those security question? Otherwise it is very difficult to answer.

Comment: The response is the page which loads the questions and the request for the submit is the login info and the answers. POST xxxxx/submit

POST data:
answer1=abcd&answer2=efge&name=test

Answer (score -1):

General answer would be:

- Use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) Post Processor to figure out what question(s) is(are) being asked
- Use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) to execute specific [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler(s) depending on what questions are.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. New to JMeter, so pardon if something is obvious. The response page where the questions are listed are technically variables in the actual code. They are replaced at run time and they are just regular labels. I have edited my main post to include the questions section.